# How do I used query string in @Query based on output of a function

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I'm trying to query using @Query annotation and it was working just fine, as it always had just one condition, but now I have multiple conditions and I want my query string to be dynamically changed based on parameters.

Let's say I have 2 lists of strings, listA and listB
I want my query to be

`@Query("SELECT l FROM location AS l WHERE l.a IN :listA")`

when listA is not empty and listB is empty,
and

`@Query("SELECT l FROM location AS l WHERE l.b IN :listB")`

when listB is not empty and listB is empty,
and

`@Query("SELECT l FROM location AS l WHERE l.a IN :listA) AND l.b IN :listB"`

when both lists are not empty.

I've been trying to see if I can get the query string from other function.

I can generate the string based on lists, but I just don't know how to put the output string in @Query() as it's in repository interface.

Comment: You can use JPA specifications

Answer (score 1):

Use `JPA Specification API`  [link](https://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Specifications](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#specifications) to achieve that. The specification class will be something like (assuming a, b are text columns):

```
public class LocationSpecification implements Specification<Location> {
    public LocationSpecification(final List<String> listA, final List<String> listB) {
        this.listA = listA;
        this.listB = listB;
    }

    private final List<String> listA;
    private final List<String> listB;

    @Override
    public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Location> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder cb) {
        List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
        if (listA != null) {
            predicates.add(root.<String>get("a").in(listA));
        }
        if (listB != null) {
            predicates.add(root.<String>get("b").in(listB));
        }
        return cb.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0]));
    }
}
```

The repository need to extend [JpaSpecificationExecutor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaSpecificationExecutor.html)

```
public interface LocationRepository 
  extends JpaRepository<Location, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Location> {}
```

and you'd call it like:

```
List<Location> results = repository.findAll(new LocationSpecification(listA, listB));
```

P.S. Written the above of the top of my head, may need some fixing.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to always rely on the @Query to do the queries.
Better option would be to create stored procedure and call them programmatically based on your conditions. Or use Criteria to generate the query dynamically [like here.](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-criteria-queries)

Answer (score 0):

[This article](https://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/) although it is old, has a nice overview/comparison between **Criteria API** / **Specifications** / **Querydsl**. Another library is **Jooq** that has a free version.

The way to solve your problem is to use one of these.

I prefer Querydsl because

- it is type-safe
- it works well with Spring Data
- you can use code completion features in the IDE

You should also consider that (currently) Querydsl it is not well maintained.